# How to Change Post Title on Apostrophe Theme: Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How do I change post title in my Apostrophe wordpress theme from its current size to h4 through css.
please help

Link to Apostrophe Theme - https://wordpress.org/themes/apostrophe/

Comment: Are you not able to change the post title by editing the post? If that is the case what problem are you facing? You need mention details of the problem.

Comment: I need to change the current heading to h4 through CSS if possible. Need help! the website is https://xttrawave.com/

Comment: If you mean that you want to change the current post heading which is a "<h1>post title</h1>" tag, and want to change that to "<h4>post title</h4>", then this is not possible via css. Via css you can change the "font-size" of h1 tag to look like h4 but you can not change the h1 tag to h4 just via css. You will have to edit your post template and change the html tag itself.

Answer (score 0):

Go inside your post -> change the title...

Comment: I meant how to change the size of the heading to h4 through CSS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the size for all your headings then go in your dashboaard Appearance->Editor locate style.css file and in the bottom of your file add:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 14px; //for example, but you can change the size to whaever
}
```